# Chern-Simons Lagrangian and gauge-fixing

Tags: condensed-matter, lagrangian-formalism, classical-field-theory, quantum-hall-effect, chern-simons-theory

**Main question**:

1. Consider (2+1)D Chern-Simons action
   $$S = \int dt d^2\mathbf r \frac{k}{4\pi} \epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda} a_\mu \partial_\nu a_\lambda.$$
   Assuming the Coulomb gauge $\nabla\cdot \mathbf a = 0$, does the above action equivalent to
   $$S' = \int dt d^2\mathbf r \frac{k}{2\pi} \epsilon_{\alpha\beta} a_0\partial_\alpha a_\beta ?$$
2. In Coulomb gauge, we can write the spatial component $a_\alpha$ using the transverse component as
   $$a_\alpha(\mathbf k, \omega) = \frac{i \epsilon^{\alpha\beta}k_\beta}{|\mathbf k|} a_T(\mathbf k, \omega).$$
   Then, how one can derive that the Fourier transform of the action becomes
   $$S = \frac{k}{4\pi} \sum_k |\mathbf k| a_0(k)^* a_T(k)?$$

**Motivation**: I am currently reading Nagaosa's book "Quantum Field theory in Condensed Matter Physics". In p.174 Eq. (6.2.37) and (6.2.39), the author claims the first question stated above. The following is the part of the book. In p.179 Eq.(6.2.59), the author claims the second question stated above.

**My trial**:

1. Assuming $a$ is perodic in time and decays sufficiently fast at spatial infinity, we can freely integrate by parts. Then, the term inside $S$ becomes
   $$\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda} a_\mu \partial_\nu a_\lambda = (a_0\partial_1a_2-a_0\partial_2a_1)+ (a_1\partial_2a_0-a_2\partial_1a_0) + (a_2\partial_0a_1-a_1\partial_3a_2).$$
   The first term is same as $\epsilon_{\alpha\beta} a_0\partial_\alpha a_\beta$. Also, integrating by parts, the second term
   $$a_1\partial_2a_0-a_2\partial_1a_0 \to a_0\partial_1a_2-a_0\partial_2a_1 = \epsilon_{\alpha\beta} a_0\partial_\alpha a_\beta.$$
   What about the third term $a_2\partial_0a_1-a_1\partial_3a_2$? I want this to be zero, but I don't know how to proceed.
2. By the straight computation, I obtain
   $$ S \sim \frac{k_2^2}{|\mathbf k|} a_T(k)^* a_0(k) + \frac{k_1^2}{|\mathbf k|} a_0(k)^* a_T(k) + \frac{i\omega k_1k_2}{|\mathbf k|^2} a_T(k)^*a_T(k),$$
   which is different from that I want.